# MVC3 with EF, error on Updating record "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am facing subject issue while working with EF DB first with MVC3.

Please note my EF model is in a class library which is referred inside a MVC project.

On adding new controller, I selected "Controller with read wirte actions and views, using Entity Framework". As a model class I selected EF's generated class and as a context I select EF context.

Running on page it display records, on clicking eidt it rendered edit view as well. Just problem is when I try to update it through error.

Please guide me.

Thanks

**EDID**
This error is not always, some time this error appears and some time it updates.

Comment: in your debug window, expand "InnerException" inner-exception ususally contains exact reasons, which might help you in fixing this error.

Comment: You definitely need to post some code if you want any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the inner excetion and then seeing profiler I realized I am entering data bigger then column size. I corrected it and it was ok after that.